# Why does express.js generate a JSON.parse error?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I installed node.js and express.js and I'm trying to use:

```
var str = { test: 'info'};
obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

but it causes an error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token 0 at Object.parse (native)**

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you parsing `Object` to `Object`?

`JSON.parse()` expects `string`:

```
var str = '{"test": "info"}';
obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically JSON.parse() expects string but you were passing object, so instead do this:

```
var original = { test: 'info'};
var str = JSON.stringify(original);
var restored = JSON.parse(str);
```

Here's helpful docs about JSON https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_native_JSON

Answer (score 1):

str is not a string, but an object. Put the whole thing into a string first, i.e.:

```
var str = '{ "test": "info"}';
obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: var str = '{ test: 'info'}';
    obj = JSON.parse(str);                                            I write, but the same mistake.

Comment: Mind your quote types, and/or make sure you escape embedded quotes.

Answer (score 1):

express.js cannot parse JSON objects on its own. Try using the body-parser

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create JSON you need to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var thing = { test: 'info' };
var json = JSON.stringify(thing);
```

If you want to parse JSON to an object you need to use `parse`. Parse expects you to use valid JSON.

```
var json = '{ "test": "info" }'; //Use double quotes for JSON
var thing = JSON.parse(json);
```

An easy way to test if you are using valid json is to use something like: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are calling `str` is actually already an object.  JSON is not necessary, pure JavaScript is all you need:

```
var obj = { test: 'info'};
```

---

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );  // JSON output
```